# How to check OR condition in JSTL <c:when>

Tags: jstl

The following code checks if List is empty, then it hides the `Dropdown` list. I want to check one more condition with it. If List has only one item then also `Dropdown` list should be hidden.

```
 <c:when test="${empty List}">
       $("#Dropdown").hide();
    </c:when>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<c:when test="${fn:length(List) <= 1}">
```

This supposes that the `functions` tag library of the JSTL has been declared at the top of the JSP page, of course:

```
 <%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
```

Or, in the latest versions of te JSP spec:

```
<c:when test="${List.size() <= 1}">
```

Note that `List` should be named `list` to adhere to the standard naming conventions.